# Can Mac (Big Sur) System extensions collect data?

Tags: audio, quicktime, midi, screen-recording

I've been meaning to install Blackhole or Background Music or other third party audio driver in order to record audio output while screen recording through QuickTime.

What I'm not sure of is whether these third party audio drivers (system extensions) collect any data or compromise privacy in any manner?

Couldn't find any policy on their GitHub docs about the same.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Comment: @agarza If there is something specific which needs to be improved in a post, the OP may benefit from having it explained to them directly.

Comment: Not a full answer: it depends on the kind of driver. Modern DriverKit drivers and System Extensions are limited in what they can do, while a Kernel Extension could do _anything_. So Big Sur System Extension solutions can still collect some data, but they cannot, for example, log your keystrokes or access arbitrary files.